# How to go back or re-display Userform after hiding it?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have this code in one command button in UserForm2:

```
 Private Sub CButton1_Click()
     UserForm1.Show
     Me.Hide
 End Sub
```

Now, `Userform1` is shown.
Then I have another code in one command button in Userform1:

```
 Private Sub CButton2_Click()
     UserForm2.Show
     Unload Me
 End Sub
```

This throws up a:

> Runtime Error: Form already displayed; can't show modally

How do I do this properly?
How do I go back to the previous `Userform` after hiding or unloading it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the problem is the order of the statements.  I found out by using the debugger that when I had the Show statements before the Hide or Unload, these last are not executed.

Try this

```
' on UserForm2
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Me.Hide
    UserForm1.Show
End Sub

' on UserForm1
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Me.Hide
    UserForm2.Show
End Sub
```

Comment: the only problem with unloading its that you loose the values filled on a form.. hidding is more appropriate

Comment: @mehow yeah, you are right.  I changed my code according to your observation.

Comment: thanks, it works. sequence in coding is really important when working with Userforms i guess.

Answer (score 3):

Change to this:

```
Private Sub CButton1_Click()
   Me.Hide
   UserForm1.Show
   Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub CButton2_Click()
   Me.Hide
   UserForm2.Show
   Unload Me
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks mate. this works too. but i have to give credit to Octavio for the explanation. :)