# Why does Userform freezes after hiding and showing it multiple times

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

Ok, i have question on hiding and showing userforms.
[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20068412/how-to-go-back-display-userform-after-hiding-it/20068820?noredirect=1#20068820) already answered it for me.

Problem is I encounter another problem.
When I go back to `Userform1` it freezes and I can't do anything at all.
Why? Do i need to add something in the code?

**Heres the summay of the code i used:**
This code prompts user to enter username and password

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub CBu_Login_Click()
Dim ws As Worksheet, rng As Range, lrow As Long, find_value As String
Dim cel As Range

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("UserName")
lrow = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set rng = ws.Range("A2:A" & lrow)
find_value = Me.TB_Username.Value
Set cel = rng.Find(What:=find_value, After:=ws.Range("A2"), LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
If Not cel Is Nothing Then
    If Me.TB_Password.Value = cel.Offset(0, 1).Value Then
        Me.Hide
        UF_Encoding.L_User.Caption = "Welcome " & cel.Offset(0, 2).Value & "!" & " You are logged in."
        UF_Encoding.TB_Operator.Text = cel.Offset(0, 2).Value
        UF_Encoding.TB_ESN_IMEI.Value = ""
        UF_Encoding.CB_PrimaryCode.Value = ""
        UF_Encoding.CB_SecondaryCode.Value = ""
        UF_Encoding.TB_Remarks.Value = ""
        UF_Encoding.TB_ESN_IMEI.SetFocus
        UF_Encoding.Show
    Else
        MsgBox "Invalid Username/Password"
    End If
Else
    MsgBox "Invalid Username/Password"
End If

End Sub
```

**This code is for logging out:**
I used Listbox here so the user can select which action to take.

```
Private Sub LB_Options_AfterUpdate()

If Me.LB_Options.Value = "Log out" Then
    Me.Hide
    Me.LB_Options.Visible = False
    UF_Login.TB_Username.Value = ""
    UF_Login.TB_Password.Value = ""
    UF_Login.Show

ElseIf Me.LB_Options.Value = "Change Password" Then
    Me.Hide
    Me.LB_Options.Visible = False
    UF_Changepass.TB_User.Value = ""
    UF_Changepass.TB_Newpass.Value = ""
    UF_Changepass.TB_Oldpass.Value = ""
    UF_Changepass.Show

ElseIf Me.LB_Options.Value = "Exit" Then
    Me.Hide
    wbDbase.Save
    wbDbase.Close
    wbEncoding.Save
    wbEncoding.Close
    Unload UF_Login
    Unload UF_Changepass
    Unload Me
End If
```

Well this does what i wan't. Log in, log out, change pass and exit.
But as I've, said the Forms freezes after 1st execution.

**Example:**
1. I initialize UF_Login and then UF_Encoding appears.
2. It works, all commandbuttons and text boxes works.
3. Then I log out using the list box.
4. When i log in again, it will show UF_Encoding but when i try to use the commanb buttons and text boxes, it doesn't work.
5. Strange thing is that the list box with log out, change pass and exit works.

I'm really having a hard time figuring out why.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Part of your problem is that you're calling forms from within forms, which can quickly get tricky, often leading to multiple instances of the same form - usually with unexpected results. Calling your forms from a macro in a regular module ensures better control. See [This](http://peltiertech.com/Excel/PropertyProcedures.html) for some guidance.

Comment: yeah that's what i thought as well. but i am wishing that maybe there's a way to go around it. I avoid doing a macro on a reg module since what i'm trying to accomplish is just show the forms to the user and not the worksheets.

Comment: Even so, you should be able to accomplish that by controlling your forms' flow from a regular macro.

Comment: would it make a difference if i put the code into a module and call it on `CB_Login_Click()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To allow multiple switches between `UserForms`, it is better to unload the forms you're not using and then just reload it when it's time to use it again. Something like:

```
Me.Hide '/* hide the initiating form first */
Load UF_Login '/* loads the form, but not shown */
With UF_Login
    .TB_Username.Value = ""
    .TB_Password.Value = ""
    .Show
End With
Unload Me '/* unload the initiating form */
```

In the `UF_Login`, a code to view the `UF_Encoding` will be added to make it look like you're actually logging in and out of the form.

```
Private Sub CB_Login_Click()

    '/* code to check log-in credentials goes here */ 
    Me.Hide
    Load UF_Encoding
    UF_Encoding.Show
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try.  It's "rough" code, and certainly needs refining, but it works, and should give you some ideas.

This goes in UF_Encoding

```
Option Explicit
'UF_Encoding form
Private msLBox As String
Private msUser As String
Public Property Let psUser(s As String)
    msUser = s
End Property
Public Property Get psLBox() As String
    psLBox = msLBox
End Property

Private Sub LB_Options_AfterUpdate()
msLBox = Me.LB_Options.Value

If Me.LB_Options.Value = "Log out" Then
    Me.Hide
    Me.LB_Options.Visible = False
    UF_Login.TB_Username.Value = ""
    UF_Login.TB_Password.Value = ""

ElseIf Me.LB_Options.Value = "Change Password" Then
    Me.Hide
    Me.LB_Options.Visible = False
    UF_Changepass.TB_User.Value = ""
    UF_Changepass.TB_Newpass.Value = ""
    UF_Changepass.TB_Oldpass.Value = ""

ElseIf Me.LB_Options.Value = "Exit" Then
    Me.Hide
    '    wbDbase.Save
    '    wbDbase.Close
    '    wbEncoding.Save
    '    wbEncoding.Close
    '    Unload UF_Login
    '    Unload UF_Changepass
    '    Unload Me
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    Me.L_User.Caption = "Welcome " & msUser & "!" & " You are logged in."
    Me.TB_Operator.Text = msUser
    msLBox = "" 'reset each time form re-entered
    Me.LB_Options.Visible = True
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Me.LB_Options.AddItem "Log out"
    Me.LB_Options.AddItem "Change Password"
    Me.LB_Options.AddItem "Exit"

    Me.TB_ESN_IMEI.Value = ""
    Me.CB_PrimaryCode.Value = ""
    Me.CB_SecondaryCode.Value = ""
    Me.TB_Remarks.Value = ""
    Me.TB_ESN_IMEI.SetFocus
End Sub
```

This goes in UF_Login

```
Option Explicit
'UF_Login form
Private msUser As String
Public Property Get psUser() As String
    psUser = msUser
End Property

Private Sub CBu_Login_Click()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, rng As Range, lrow As Long, find_value As String
    Dim cel As Range

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("UserName")
    lrow = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = ws.Range("A2:A" & lrow)
    find_value = Me.TB_Username.Value
    Set cel = rng.Find(What:=find_value, After:=ws.Range("A2"), LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    If Not cel Is Nothing Then
        If Me.TB_Password.Value = cel.Offset(0, 1).Value Then
            msUser = cel.Offset(0, 2).Value 'save user name
            Me.Hide
        Else
            MsgBox "Invalid Username/Password"
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "Invalid Username/Password"
    End If

End Sub
```

This goes in UF_Changepass

```
Option Explicit
'UF_Changepass form
Private Sub CMDok_Click()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, rng As Range
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("UserName")
    ws.Columns("B:B").Find(Me.TB_Oldpass, , xlValues, xlWhole, , , False).Value = Me.TB_Newpass
    Me.Hide
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Click()
```

This code goes in a regular module

```
Option Explicit
    Dim fLogin As UF_Login
    Dim fEnc As UF_Encoding
    Dim fChg As UF_Changepass

Sub main()
    Dim s As String
'   initialize all 3 forms
    Set fLogin = New UF_Login
    Set fEnc = New UF_Encoding
    Set fChg = New UF_Changepass

    fLogin.Show '1st time

'   re-display main form until done
    Do
        fEnc.psUser = fLogin.psUser 'pass user name to main form
        fEnc.Show
        s = fEnc.psLBox 'get listbox value
        If s <> "Exit" Then showAuxForms s
    Loop Until s = "Exit"

'   done with forms
    Unload fLogin
    Unload fEnc
    Unload fChg
    Set fLogin = Nothing
    Set fEnc = Nothing
    Set fChg = Nothing
End Sub

Sub showAuxForms(s As String)
    If s = "Log out" Then
        fLogin.Show
    ElseIf s = "Change Password" Then
        fChg.Show
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: yes i will try this one. still can't seem to grasp the code just by looking at it. Also my first time to try `Public Property`. This is where i have minimal understanding and does finding it hard to get to the code. anyways, i'll do additional searches and give you feedback asap.

Comment: Property Let & Property Get is a way to pass data between the form and your macro.  You could do it by declaring a Public variable(s) instead, but this method gives you more control.  You might find [THIS](http://peltiertech.com/Excel/PropertyProcedures.html) to be helpful.